# Swift Dictionaries: is it NOT possible to have an Array be the Value for a Key?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

I wanna declare a couple of Arrays and assign them as the Values for Keys in a Dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   let colorsArray = ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"]
   let numbersArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

   let myDictionary = ["Colors" : colorsArray, "Numbers" : numbersArray]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // etc.
```

This produces the following error:

```
ViewController.Type does not have a member named 'colorsArray'
```

So....

I tried modifying my Dictionary declaration like so:

```
let myDictionary:Dictionary<String, Array> = ["Colors" : colorsArray, "Numbers" : numbersArray]
```

And that gives me an even *better* error:

```
Reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>
```

I tried all sorts of other fixes - nothing works.

This was/is a piece of cake in Objective-C, but in Swift...?

**SOLUTION**: 
Moving the dictionary declaration statement into `viewDidLoad` fixed it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   let colorsArray = ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"]
   let numbersArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myDictionary = ["Colors" : colorsArray, "Numbers" : numbersArray]
        // etc.
```

I don't quite get why that is, but it does work now.

Comment: [work for me](http://pastebin.com/BWSQb8QH). and try this `let myDictionary:Dictionary<String, Array<String>> = ["Colors" : colorsArray, "Numbers" : numbersArray]`

Comment: I tried that! That was one of the many variations I tried - cause it looked right - but I got that same error `ViewController.Type does not have a member named 'colorsArray'`   How is this possible?  Did you do this in Playgrounds or in an actual Xcode project?

Comment: I tried in REPL. you need to show the whole code. I think you have code in `class Foo { /*code here*/ }`. but I only tried in `func foo() {  /*code here*/}`

Comment: What you said put me on the right track - check out Edited question.

Comment: Going to be some long answers below, but the short answer is, that you can't use self in the initialization process until all properties have been assigned a value.  Hence, since myDictionary is still unassigned, you can't use self.colorsArray to initialize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you're not initializing `colorsArray`, `numbersArray`, and `myDictionary` so much as you are specifying a default value that will be used if `init()` does not set one. You're not allowed to reference other properties in the default value of a property, because (I'm speculating a bit) the order in which they are set is not guaranteed.

Something as simple as

```
class Test {
    let a = 3
    let b = 5
    let c = a * b
}
```

fails in the same way your initial code did. To set `c` or `myDictionary` as desired, we must do so in an initializer, instead of using a default value:

```
class Test {

    let a = 3
    let b = 5        
    let c: Int

    init () {
        c = a*b
    }
}
```

(Note that immutable properties are mutable inside `init`, which is how we get away with using `let c`.)

So, the solution that most closely corresponds to your initial code is:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    let colorsArray = ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"]
    let numbersArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

    let myDictionary: Dictionary<String, Array<String>>

    init() {
        myDictionary = ["Colors" : colorsArray, "Numbers" : numbersArray]
        super.init()
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Your speculation is certainly an interesting one :-) Sounds plausible for sure. Wrapping one's head around Swift - after years of Obj.C is - well, no fun! :-) (Like how they want you to call `super.init()` _after_ you init'd your vars...)  Growing pains - it'll take a bit.  Had this figured out but since you took the time to compose answer I'll mark yours as correct. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. This was vexing me as well.